# Azure AD Reporting API: Inconsistent results between portal and API

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using the [Getting started with the Azure AD Reporting API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-reporting-api-getting-started/) PowerShell example with some additional steps to take advantage of nextLink and grab all the data in my date range.  The data consistently comes back missing the oldest 24 hours worth of logs.  I can see the logs exist via the portal or by extending the date range of my query (which then returns all but oldest 24 hours of that range).

Example request:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headerParams -Uri "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantdomain/reports/auditEvents?api-version=beta&amp;`$filter=eventTime%20gt%202015-12-01T08:00:00Z%20and%20eventTime%20lt%202015-12-04T08:00:00Z"
```

Not sure it's worth it's own post, but the query is also returning no data for updatedProperties.  Has anyone able to have either of these issues work for their tenant?

Comment: I've seen the same behavior.  Haven't got any response from MS to [my post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/49f2c08f-9acd-4e1d-8fe4-730c7121c07a/filter-in-aad-audit-report-api-not-working-as-expected?forum=WindowsAzureAD) on the MSDN forums.

Comment: @BenV, I'll get someone to address your question on MSDN. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: @Dani: I provided details in [my post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/49f2c08f-9acd-4e1d-8fe4-730c7121c07a/filter-in-aad-audit-report-api-not-working-as-expected?forum=WindowsAzureAD) on the MSDN forums.

Comment: @BenV, Thanks for speaking up as well.  :)

Comment: @Rick_2CA Can you give an example of the time ranges you used?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret   Some fail message formatting for me.  Let's try [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jZaYBnpZ).

Answer (score 1):

We looked into the issue and found that you need to use the `ge` operator to match the results you see in the UI. The `gt` operator adds 24 hours to your query parameter and hence the reason you are not seeing the data you see in the UI.

Comment: Doing eventtime gt $DaysAgo is now pulling the same data as eventtime ge $DaysAgo where it wasn't previously.  I can't test the date range however because the format of the url in @odata.nextLink is throwing an error.  Details here:  [http://pastebin.com/Vtj2Ym1f](http://pastebin.com/Vtj2Ym1f).

Comment: For some reason when I do $DaysAgo the @odata.nextLink works fine though.

`https://graph.windows.net/tenantdomain.com/reports/auditEvents?api-version=beta&%24filter=eventTime+gt+2016-02-20T17%3a31%3a45Z&%24skip=1000`

It's the same format that doesn't work with the date range.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the second half of your question:

UpdatedProperties only includes properties that were changed, and only if they are one of a limited set of properties. for user updates, you can see which ones are included at: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/active-directory-reporting-audit-events/#quotupdate-userquot-attributes

If you don't see any properties (and their before/after values) in UpdatedProperties, it means there was some other attribute changed.

Regarding the first question (not an answer): I'll direct this post to someone who can answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Philippe.  I have found events in the portal that logged the property changes.  Corresponding events pulled by the API have never populated updatedProperties.  "Change user license" is the event we're most interested in to begin with and the "Update user" event that should log what changed is always empty via the API.  We generate more than 1k logs a day so the portal doesn't always work to find the event we need.

Comment: Interesting, and unexpected. Well look into this further as well.

Comment: Following up on this topic.  Thanks.

Comment: @Rick_2CA We'll get back to you in the next few days on this. Thanks for following up.